# Prompts when numbers are added together it just puts the number and the other number together

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am working on a geometry style like calculator using javascript, and I need user input. But when the user, for example, inputs 55 and the other also 55 the sum of the number will be 5555 when I'd like it to be 110.

Javascript Code:

```html
function ftmad2(){
    let angle1 = prompt("Please enter the first angle:");
    let angle2 = prompt("Please enter the second angle:");
    sumAngle = angle1 + angle2;
    console.log(sumAngle);
    let result = 180-sumAngle;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: If you read the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) you will see that *"result is a string containing the text entered by the user, or null."*. So with that information you can see that you are concatenating strings, not adding numbers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common issue; it is reading 55 as a string, rather than a number, do:

```
sumAngle = parseInt(angle1, 10) + parseInt(angle2, 10);
```

Comment: common issue sounds like it should be a dupe. :)

Comment: @epascarello absolutly! It [scary](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+concatenate+site%3Astackoverflow.com) how many questions like this are out there.

Answer (score 0):

Current senerio

```
"55"+"55"  //which will  return 5555 obviously
```

Use `parseInt` to convert string to int because your both value `angle1` and `angle2` coming in `string` format, you should convert into `int` before `sum`.

required senerio

```
   55 + 55  //which will return 110
```

```js
function ftmad2(){
    let angle1 = prompt("Please enter the first angle:");
    let angle2 = prompt("Please enter the second angle:");
    angle1 = parseInt(angle1);
    angle2 = parseInt(angle2);
    sumAngle = angle1 + angle2;
    console.log(sumAngle);
    let result = 180-sumAngle;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

ftmad2();
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` returns a string.

When you do `angle1 + angle2` you're joining two strings instead of summing two numbers.

In order for this to work, you'll have to transform the strings in numbers first. Like this:

```js
function ftmad2(){
    let angle1 = prompt("Please enter the first angle:");
    let angle2 = prompt("Please enter the second angle:");
    sumAngle = parseFloat(angle1) + parseFloat(angle2);
    console.log(sumAngle);
    let result = 180-sumAngle;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
ftmad2();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```